# Using patterns in ReplaceAll to extract elements from tuples at arbitrary depths

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, replacement

Please consider the following:

I need to extract from `MyList` all last parts of each 3-tuple.

```
MyList={
         {{0.`, 2, 5}},
         {{0.`, 1, 8},{10.`, 10, 10},{10.`, 6, 2.5}},
         {{0.`, 1.25, 10},{0.`, 8.9, 100}}
       };
```

I tried to apply the following but it did not work:

```
MyList /. {a_Number, b_Number, c_Number} :> c
```

Please note, that `a`,`b` and `c` must be of `Number`, otherwise the last 3-tuple of `MyList[[2]]` would be extracted to, since it `MyList[[2]]` itself represents a 3-tuple.

The result must be:

```
{{5},{8,10,2.5},{10,100}}
```

Comment: did you mean to write `list` (with a lower case `l`)?

Comment: @R.M: Thanks for the comment. Please see edit.

Comment: Also, there's no type `Number`. Consider `_?NumberQ`

Comment: Indeed, integers have head `Integer`, reals have `Real`, rationals have `Rational` and complex numbers have `Complex` as head. So, no `Number`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any time you write a pattern, you should stop and ask yourself a couple of questions — *"Is this really a `Head`?"*,  *"Does this pattern test return `True` or `False`"*... [`Number`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Number.html), which represents a real/integer in `Read` is different from `?NumericQ`, which is a pattern test. In this case, the latter is what you need.

```
MyList /. {__, x_?NumericQ} :> x
(* {{5}, {8, 10, 2.5}, {10, 100}} *)
```

Alternately, you could also map `Last` to the appropriate level in your list:

```
Map[Last, MyList, {Depth[list] - 2}]
(* {{5}, {8, 10, 2.5}, {10, 100}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
MyList /. {_, _, c_?NumberQ} :> c
```

> {{5}, {8, 10, 2.5}, {10, 100}}